# Knowing when the variance in a time series is changing

Tags: time-series, heteroscedasticity

A basic question, but one I have not found. It is said that if your variance is changing over time you should log it before running ARIMA. This is a form of non-stationarity but I have not seen suggestions that you address it by differencing. My question is what is the best way to tell the variance is changing. I have a hard time telling this looking at graphs, which is the only way I have run into testing for it. There has to be a formal test.

Comment: The advice you refer to is incorrect. Logging is specifically for when the variance is proportional to the level of the series (i.e. the variance is larger when the level is higher), not generically when it is "changing over time".

Comment: Thank you. I thought when they said changing they over time not relative to a mean. Can you even run time series models if the variance changes over time (I am not sure differencing deals with that). But my question would remain the same, how would you test for this, do test of heteroskedasticity work for time series?